# Is there a function from Package aws.s3, or other package in R, that returns file info?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to retrieve information about size, date and time of creation of a file stored in AWS S3. I used to work with file.info("MyFile.csv") when I was storing the files in regular server, as I changed for a AWS S3 this file.info no longer works, returning NA´s. I need a similar function from aws.s3 or any other package.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with R or the aws.s3 package for R. However, the way that you get the metadata you refer to (size, date etc) for an object on S3 is to make a [HEAD object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html) call.

This looks as though it is the cloudyr/aws.s3 equivalent:

https://rdrr.io/github/cloudyr/aws.s3/man/head_object.html

The documentation there refers to 'content-length', which would be your file size. The head object call also returns 'Last-Modified'. As I understand it, 'Last-Modified' is actually the creation date of the object, although if it has been 'overwritten' by a more recent version it will be the creation date of the latest version.

If versioning is enabled, then you could do a versioned HEAD request to get the creation date of the first version. I don't know whether R supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @redbirdo,  i followed this path that you indicated, and i got to the head_object()function. It, indeed retrieves metadata about the file, i had a little trouble getting the content of this metadata into a variable in order to show it in a shiny application that keeps me updated about uploaded files. However, i solved this by using function attr(), and finally reaching for the specific information inside the metadata. 
Ex: Last_Modification = attr(head_object("MyFile.csv", bucket = "MyBucketName"), "last-modified") and so on for other metadata information.